# How do I generate multi-word terms recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

Say I have a string of words: `'a b c d e f'`.  I want to generate a list of multi-word terms from this string.

Word order matters. The term `'f e d'` shouldn't be generated from the above example.

**Edit:** Also, words should not be skipped.  `'a c'`, or `'b d f'` shouldn't be generated.

**What I have right now:**

```
doc = 'a b c d e f'
terms= []
one_before = None
two_before = None
for word in doc.split(None):
    terms.append(word)
    if one_before:
        terms.append(' '.join([one_before, word]))
    if two_before:
        terms.append(' '.join([two_before, one_before, word]))
    two_before = one_before
    one_before = word

for term in terms:
    print term
```

**Prints:**

```
a
b
a b
c
b c
a b c
d
c d
b c d
e
d e
c d e
f
e f
d e f
```

How would I make this a recursive function so that I can pass it a variable maximum number of words per term?

**Application:**

I'll be using this to generate multi-word terms from readable text in HTML documents.  The overall goal is a latent semantic analysis of a large corpus (about two million documents).  This is why keeping word order matters (Natural Language Processing and whatnot).

Comment: For simplicity I substituted single letters for words.

Comment: did you mean "variable maximum number of terms per words"? because it doesn't make sense to me in current form.

Comment: I think the real question here is, does it need to be recursive to do the job?  Is there a requirement for recursion here?

Comment: @SilentGhost, If I pass the function 'max_words=4', I want to get back terms where len(term.split(None)) <= 4.

Comment: @Dan Coates, No it's not a requirement, I was under the impression that a recursive function could perform the analysis faster than a loop, but after further research I find that may not be the case.

Comment: Recursive functions are often easier to understand (for the right problems), but there's no particular why they should be faster than a good iterative solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't recursive, but I think it does what you want.

```
doc = 'a b c d e f'
words = doc.split(None)
max = 3          


for index in xrange(len(words)):    
    for n in xrange(max):
        if index + n < len(words):           
            print ' '.join(words[index:index+n+1])
```

And here's a recursive solution:

```
def find_terms(words, max_words_per_term):       
    if len(words) == 0: return []
    return [" ".join(words[:i+1]) for i in xrange(min(len(words), max_words_per_term))] + find_terms(words[1:], max_words_per_term)


doc = 'a b c d e f'
words = doc.split(None) 
for term in find_terms(words, 3):
    print term
```

Here's the recursive function again, with some explaining variables and comments.

```
def find_terms(words, max_words_per_term):   

    # If there are no words, you've reached the end. Stop.    
    if len(words) == 0:
        return []      

    # What's the max term length you could generate from the remaining 
    # words? It's the lesser of max_words_per_term and how many words 
    # you have left.                                                         
    max_term_len = min(len(words), max_words_per_term)       

    # Find all the terms that start with the first word.
    initial_terms = [" ".join(words[:i+1]) for i in xrange(max_term_len)]

    # Here's the recursion. Find all of the terms in the list 
    # of all but the first word.
    other_terms = find_terms(words[1:], max_words_per_term)

    # Now put the two lists of terms together to get the answer.
    return initial_terms + other_terms
```

Comment: It looks like I'll have to use the first solution you provided.  Python won't let a function recurs more than 999 times.  My test document had about 1750 words and it is on the small side.

Comment: That makes sense. The recursive solution was fun to work out, but not really practical.

Comment: If you really want to have deep recursion, you can increase the recursion limit with sys.setrecursionlimit. But the iterative solution is probably better here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you should make your function a generator and then generate required number of terms. You would need to change `print` to `yield` (and make the whole block function, obviously).

You might have a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) module as well, it's fairly useful for kind of work you do.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this? You can instead just use a for loop and [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: Good suggestion, but I need the order to be preserved. Example: 'a b c' creates ['a', 'b', 'a b', 'c', 'b c', 'a b c'], but not 'b a' or 'c b a'.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it also shouldn't skip words.  The doc "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence" shouldn't have "brown fence" as a term.  Is there a way to use itertools to do this?

Comment: Not that I can think of at the moment. I did notice that after I replied, but yeah. Still, itertools is nice. It should always be the first place to look.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is N-gram algorithm. That will give you [a,ab,b,bc,c,cd,...].